# use case of "Moving to, Shifting To, Relocate to"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-difference

We are going to new office location in Austin. So if some one will ask, where is your new office then how do i respond to them

3 words has similar meaning as per my understanding.

Our office Moving ot/Shifting to/ Relocating to Austin.

Please give me suggestion which is the word correct to use here.

Thanks & Regards,
Rameshkumar

Comment: Third one is the best as it sounds the most professional. But moving to is OK and is used, too. Shifting to is wrong.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "When we informed someone" mean?  "Moving to" is present, "Relocated to" is past. Is the move to a new location planned for the future, currently in progress, or already completed?

Comment: @verbose I hope now my question will clear for you

Answer (score 0):

"Moving to" (or "moved to") is correct in all situations.

"Relocated" is just a more complicated way of saying "moved"; the meaning is the same. (I disagree that "relocated" is somehow more professional than "moved" -- "relocated" is wordier and more complicated, but why must professional language be wordy and complicated?)

"Shift" is technically correct, but the implication is a bit different -- "shift" implies a minor move.

Here are some examples from [the M-W definition of shift](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shift):

> - I shifted the bag to my other shoulder.
> - They shifted him to a different department.
> - He nervously shifted from foot to foot.

Each of these examples uses "shift" as a small move.

"Shift" might make sense if your office is moving to a new floor in the same building, or even across town. But if it's a major move, the implications of "shift" are not quite right.